# AWS ELB Application health check URL returns 404

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an `symfony2` application uploaded to AWS ELB. Everytime I am going to upload a new **zip** version of my application the health becomes **severe** and upon checking the access_logs I found out that the AWS is not seeing the the **Application health check URL** that I set on the configuration.

My Config.

[image]

And im pretty sure that the `status.php` is present on the `/web/satus.php`

Is there any other reason that could result to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the app work fine outside of the health check? Is the "public" directory set correctly (apparently to "/web")? Are there any Apache rewrite rules or similar that are rewriting the request for that php script to the application entry point, when then becomes a 404 when there's no "/status.php" route defined?

Comment: Hi @mzulch when you said "Does the app work fine outside of the health check?" I dont really get it sorry. I am new to aws and Im just maintaining this setup apparently so I really find it hard to check on everything. 

What Ive don so far is I downloaded the latest working **zip** build then do some changes on it then I do `git archive ....` but when I upload the same version even when I just added a `console.log()` on the `twig`, the problem persist.

Comment: sounds like normal beanstalk behavior, it restart the web servers when deploying your code, which causes some downtime. that's the reason ELB is used. there shouldn't be downtime.